# How to to use embed code of a react app to be included in wordpress with server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, plugins

I am struggling with a requirement of adding react app embed code in one of the WordPress pages, it is working smoothly and showing what it is meant to show.

The embed code consists of a js file and a CSS file, with a class and ID.

```
<script defer="defer" src="scriptlocation.js"></script>
<link href="stylelocation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="assignid"></div>
```

Now the requirement is to make it load serverside, its text should be inserted into view source HTML.

Is there a way to achieve this in WordPress? or it needs to be done on react app part and then generate some special embed code for this requirement?

Any plugin or suggestion is highly appreciated.